# How to use postmark email on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, html-email, postmark

I am new to node.js and not able to figure out how to reference js library postmark.js in node.js.

```
  var POSTMARK_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var postmark = require("postmark")(POSTMARK_KEY);

postmark.send({
    "From": from, 
    "To": to, 
    "Subject": subject, 
    "TextBody": emailBody
}, function (err, to) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
}
console.log("Email sent to: %s", to);
});
```

I tried above code but not sure how to use postmark.js

Is there any easy way to have html email functionality using html templates in js?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "HtmlBody field to send html messages through postmark:

```
    postmark.send({
    "From": from, 
    "To": to, 
    "Subject": subject, 
    "TextBody": emailBody,
    "HtmlBody": "<h1>hellow</h1>"
}, function (err, to) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
}
console.log("Email sent to: %s", to);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In official document it is described here with example
https://postmarkapp.com/developer/integration/official-libraries#node-js

> ```
> // Install with npm
> npm install postmark --save
> // Require
> var postmark = require("postmark");
>
> // Example request
> var serverToken = "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx";
> var client = new postmark.ServerClient(serverToken);
>
> client.sendEmail({
>     "From": "sender@example.com",
>     "To": "receiver@example.com",
>     "Subject": "Test",
>     "TextBody": "Hello from Postmark!" 
> });
> ```

In order to send html body you can send `"HtmlBody": "<h1>some html in string form</h1>"` along with  `"TextBody": "Hello from Postmark!"`

like this:

```
client.sendEmail({
    "From": "sender@example.com",
    "To": "receiver@example.com",
    "Subject": "Test",
    "TextBody": "Hello from Postmark!"
    "HtmlBody": "<h1>some html in string form</h1>" 
});
```

which they have described here: https://postmarkapp.com/developer/api/email-api#send-a-single-email

Answer (score 1):

The method to send email using a template vi API with NodeJs is

`sendEmailWithTemplate()`

I could not esaily find this in the doc for NodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

You can find most of the information in the [official wiki](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark.js/wiki/Templates).

To send an email with a template use:

```
client.sendEmailWithTemplate({
    TemplateId:1234567,
    From: "from@example.com",
    To: "to@example.com",
    TemplateModel: {company: "wildbit"}
});
```